# Why can't I connect to my MariaDB server from my mac, but I can connect from a Docker container on the same machine?

Tags: networking, docker, database, mariadb

I have set up a MariaDB server on `db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com`, port 6612. I have the following situation from the command line on my local laptop (macOS):

```
$ mysql -h db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com -P 6612
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com' (60)

$ docker run -ti maria-client mysql -u [redacted] -p[redacted] -P 6612 -h db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com -e 'SELECT version()'
+---------------------------+
| version()                 |
+---------------------------+
| 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1 |
+---------------------------+
```

`maria-client` is a docker container built using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt update && apt install -y mariadb-client
```

The server at `db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com` is running Ubuntu 22.04 on Digital Ocean, with MariaDB 10.6 installed and configured to listen on all interfaces, and on port 6612. I also have UFW active and allowing TCP connections on port 6612 from anywhere. The networking works (as evidenced by the fact that the connection from the Docker container works).

Here are some relevant version strings:

mysql (MariaDB) on the laptop:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.10-MariaDB, for osx10.17 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

mysql (MariaDB) in the docker container on the laptop:

```
$ docker run -ti maria-client mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.7-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

server MariaDB:

```
$ mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Ubuntu 22.04)
```

I've been going at this as if it's a version mismatch issue, because I've encountered connectivity problems with MariaDB and version mismatches before.

Clearly the problem is not network connectivity, since I can connect using the Docker containerized mariadb, right? So why can I connect from the Docker container on macOS but not the native mysql (MariaDB) client on the same device?

Comment: This definitely would never be a client/server mismatch issue. Maybe you have had issues with MariaDB in an edge case, but in general MySQL clients are very compatible with different server versions. Have you tried using `mysql -u[username] -p -h db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com -P 6612`? How is authentication handled? In a local `.my.cnf` file on your Mac or something similar?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that connections from the `maria-client` Docker container do, in fact, work fine. It was probably confusing that the original post had that command returning an error.

Comment: Also telnet says this:

`$ telnet db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com 6612 Trying 164.92.127.60... 
 Connected to db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com.  Escape character is '^]'. 5.5.5-10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1-qy,kZQW��@wZ<[7@zhxC$mysql_native_password`

Comment: Well, what the heck is that `kZQW��`. I wonder if there is some issue related to UTF-8 characters in your password that works fine in Docker but not in macOS since this diamond  question marks `�` show up when UTF-8 characters show up when the encoding is out of range. Like reading UTF-8 characters in a Latin (Windows-1252) connection. Try checking the Maria DB connection encoding versus your macOS terminal character encoding. Sometimes this can be solved by non-interactively setting a password. Look at this answer for [an idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597587/30848) on how to do that.

Comment: I think the garbled characters are just a result of the fact that MariaDB is using a binary protocol on port 6612. I am in fact setting the password directly on the command line with `-pmypassword`, no space

Comment: Also the password is all ASCII characters.

Comment: Genuinely stumped here. I assure you that I don’t think this is a client/server mismatch for MariaDB. Might be a config setting that is different? But MySQL servers and clients are so fundamental that they wouldn’t choke like that unless there is a massive version/driver difference.

Comment: Can you do a `nc -vz db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com 6612` from your Mac?

Comment: `$ nc -vz db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com 6612 \\ Connection to db.bestalbumsintheuniverse.com port 6612 [tcp/*] succeeded!`

Comment: Do you have any firewalls in place, something like little snitch? Clearly a simple tcp connect works, but from MySQL client it fails, so either a firewall explicitly blocking the app or client/server incompatibility is all I can think of. Can you try a different version of the MySQL client?

Comment: I do not have any firewalls running on the mac. I even checked the system firewall, and googled "outbound firewall" for macOS, but it seems that's something that has to be set up extra. In case it makes a difference, I cannot connect from a Ruby on Rails client using `mysql2` either, which is the main problem and I'm using the `mysql` CLI to try and verify.

Answer (score 0):

I was at an AirBnB (not my home network) and this cleared up once I was back on my own network. Must have been some odd network config (though I still don't understand why it worked from the Docker container on the same machine).